# Dynamically pass variable names as Y axis names in Multiple Y axis Plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, shiny-reactivity

Following the one of the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812466/r-multiple-y-axis-interactive-plot) I want to create a multiple y axis graph on plotly .

I have created a shiny example and I would like the user to:

1. choose the variable to be on Y axis from a selectInput and pass variable name to the corresponding y axis
2. change the order and number of Y axes depending on the number and names of variable selected.

Here is my code with manually selected data for Y axis:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(plotly)

      data <- data.frame (
           Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
           Weight = c(56, 60, 67, 65, 70),
           Height = c(160, 165, 168, 171, 173),
           BMI = c(21.9, 22.0, 23.7, 22.2, 23.4),
           Girth = c(32, 33, 34, 34, 33)
          )



  ui <-  fluidPage(
             selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                      c("Weight(Kg)","Height(cm)","BMI(kg/m2)", "Girth(cm)"),
                      multiple=TRUE),                   
             plotlyOutput(outputId = "Graph") )   
              
    
    
 server <- function(input, output) {
        output$Graph <-renderPlotly({
                          plot_ly(data, x = ~data$Year, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
                         add_lines(y = ~data[, 2], name='Weight(Kg)', line = list(color = "red")) %>%
                         add_lines(y = ~data[, 3], name='Height(cm)', yaxis='y2', line = list(color = "orange")) %>%
                         add_lines(y = ~data[, 4], name='BMI(kg/m2)', yaxis='y3', line = list(color = "darkgreen")) %>%     
  
                 layout(
                      xaxis = list(title = "time", domain = c(0.5,1)),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Weight(Kg)', side = "left", color = "red", position = 0,
                            anchor = 'free'),
                     yaxis2 = list(title = 'Height(cm)', side = "left", color = "orange", 
                         overlaying = "y", anchor = 'free', position = 0.1),
                     yaxis3 = list(title = 'BMI(kg/m2)', side = "left", 
                             overlaying = "y", anchor = 'free', color = "darkgreen", position = 0.2),
                     yaxis4 = list(title = 'Y-axis 4', side = "left", 
                            overlaying = "y", anchor = 'free', color = "purple", position = 0.3),
                     yaxis5 = list(title = 'Y-axis 5',side = "left", 
                             overlaying = "y", anchor = 'free', color = "brown", position = 0.4),
                     showlegend = T
                   )

               })

        }
   shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be close to what you want.

The main idea is that you can create a plot with separate commands:

```r
p <- plotly(...)
p <- p %>% add_lines(...)
p <- p %>% add_lines(...)
```

The difficult part is how to apply the layout with a custom parameter name:

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame (
  Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
  Weight = c(56, 60, 67, 65, 70),
  Height = c(160, 165, 168, 171, 173),
  BMI = c(21.9, 22.0, 23.7, 22.2, 23.4),
  Girth = c(32, 33, 34, 34, 33)
)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
              c("Weight(Kg)" = "Weight","Height(cm)" = "Height","BMI(kg/m2)" = "BMI", "Girth(cm)" = "Girth"),
              multiple=TRUE),
  plotlyOutput(outputId = "Graph")
)

colors <- c("red", "orange", "purple", "darkgreen", "brown")

server <- function(input, output) {
  basePlot <- reactive({
    plot_ly(data, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "time", domain = c(0.5,1)), showlegend = TRUE)
  })

  output$Graph <- renderPlotly({
    p <- basePlot()
    for (i in seq_along(input$variable)) {
      variable <- input$variable[[i]]

      p <- p %>%
        add_lines(x = ~Year, y = as.formula(paste0("~", variable)), name = variable, yaxis = paste0("y", i), line = list(color = colors[i]))

      position <- 0.5 - (i - 1) * 0.1
      layoutArgs <- list(p, list(title = variable, side = "left", color = colors[i], overlaying = "y", anchor = 'free', position = position))
      names(layoutArgs) <- c("p", paste0("yaxis", i))

      p <- do.call(layout, layoutArgs)

    }
    p
  })

}
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

This code does not work for the first axis. Here you need additional logic to call the parameter `yaxis` instead of `yaxis1` and also drop the yaxis parameter from the add_lines call

[image]

Comment: Thank you at @hundertdrei .... is this possible with a selectizeInput so as to control the max number of variables selected ?

Comment: @Rnoob yes you could use selectizeInput the same way and control the maximum number of items by using the `maxItems` options as documented in https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md: `selectizeInput(..., options = list(maxItems = 5)`